# numberOfTouchesRequired only working for :1 / only working on iPad

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I set my GestureRecognizer like this

```
     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
```

and the selector:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
NSLog(@"yyeyyyyeyyyyyeyyyyye");
}
```

The class is a subclass of UIView and I want the selector to be fired on the third time - but it only works when setting numberOfTapsRequired to 1.

I wondered why the `gestureRecognizer` never recognized anything so I changed and swapped so many things until I realized it's working perfectly fine except that it won't do anything when the numberOfTapsRequired is anything but 1.

Any ideas about this?

EDIT: It somehow does work on iPads with iOS 7 and iOS 8. I would have guessed there is something with the constraints limiting the touch area but the 1 click does work on all devices so what else can be the difference here?

Comment: When you set `numberOfTapsRequired` to 3 it means you need to triple-tap for it to be recognized. Are you doing a triple-tap or are you touching with three fingers? Huge difference.

Comment: I am tapping it 3 times within like half a second or something, thanks tho